# Problems with ItemRevenue when adding content and keyword dimensions.

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are using the Google Analytics API to try to get the itemRevenue from a link. We're currently working in the explorer.

Example: http://www.yoururl.com?utm_source=uniquesource&medium=medium&utm_camapaign=campaign&utm_content=content&utm_term=term

When we filter by utm_source==uniquesource, we see the item revenue at 506220.

When we add source, medium, and campaign as dimensions, we see a single row with columns for each of these dimensions, and the item revenue is still 506220 (as expected).

However, when we add the dimensions for content and keyword, we see the itemRevenue drop to 7,000.25. We're not sure why this isn't matching the 506220 since we are just adding dimensions. It also makes no sense why it became a decimal since it should be an integer.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does the response [contain sampled data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#containsSampledData)?

Comment: Yes, is there a way around the sampling?

Comment: Yes [Google Analytics Premium](https://www.google.com/analytics/premium/) has higher sampling threshold and access to [Unsampled Reports](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUnsampledReports). But you could also request a smaller date range or try setting [sampling level](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel) to `HIGHER_PRECISION`.